# Dynamically create scipy.stats distribution from methods of another class

Tags: python, scipy, scipy.stats

I have created a class which represents a statistical simulation. One aspect of that is a distribution of *p*-values, and the class contains methods characterizing that distribution:

```py
class Simulation:
    ...
    def pdf_p(self, p):
        ...
    def cdf_p(self, p):
        ...
    def ppf_p(self, P):
        ...
    def rvs_p(self, size):
        ...
```

I would now like to expose that distribution also as a `scipy.stats`-style distribution object. To do so, the `__init__` method of my class contains a statement

```py
self.p = PValueDist(self.pdf_p, self.cdf_p, self.ppf_p, self.rvs_p)
```

where the class `PValueDist` is defined as

```py
from scipy.stats import rv_continuous

class PValueDist (rv_continuous):
    def __init__(self, pdf, cdf, ppf, rvs):
        self._pdf = pdf
        self._cdf = cdf
        self._ppf = ppf
        self._rvs = rvs
        super().__init__(self)
```

This seems to work, but I'm wondering whether it is the *right* or *canonical* way to do it?

Of course I could also make `Simulation` a subclass of `rv_continuous` and rename my methods. However, the simulation comprises several different distributions, and identifying the simulation with one of them doesn't seem semantically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems OK. Several things to watch out for: 1) scipy.stats distributions are instances, so don't forget to create one, 2) if the support is not a default ((0, inf) IIRC), set them in the__init__ .

Comment: 1) I did instantiate, as shown in the question. Or do I misunderstand something? 2) I thought that's the default support of parameters, not of the RV itself? Anyway, it's p-values, so the support is [0, 1].

Comment: By the support I mean the support of the distribution, `[a, b]`, where, say, `pdf(x)` takes `x\in [a, b]`. If it's `[0, 1]`, then you want `super().__init__(self, a=0, b=1)` and define `_argcheck`

Comment: "Whether a shape parameter is valid is decided by an _argcheck method (which defaults to checking that its arguments are strictly positive.)" – My distribution doesn't have numerical parameters, it represents a specific fixed distribution defined by the copied methods, so AFAICS `_argcheck` doesn't apply.

Comment: But you seem to be right about `a=0, b=1` though.

Comment: Since I don't have parameters, I'm wondering whether I should inherit from `rv_frozen`?

Comment: Inheriting from rv_frozen is unlikely to do much good. Just inherit from rv_coutinuous